# Why doesn't my API work when I use info from an env file in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, api, environment-variables, gatsby

I have a React app where I access data from an API.

I works perfectly when I hard code all the info in my API function, but when I try to get it from an .env file, it does not work.

Below is the API code:

```
const [data, setDatas] = useState()
let myHeaders = new Headers();
const getDatas = async () => {
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Request-Headers", process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_CONTROL);
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", process.env.REACT_APP_BEARER);
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    try {
        let response = await fetch(
            process.env.REACT_APP_DATAS_API, requestOptions);
        let result = await response.json();
        setDatas(result)
    } catch (err) { console.error(err); }
};
console.log(datas && Object.values(datas))
```

Below is what the .env file looks like:

```
REACT_APP_PROJECTS_API=https://this-is-the-api-uri

REACT_APP_ACCESS_CONTROL=this-is-the-access-control

REACT_APP_BEARER=Bearer this-is-the-bearer-token
```

And below is the contents of my gatsby-config.js file:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Site Name`,
    siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`
  },
  plugins: ["gatsby-plugin-image", "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet", "gatsby-plugin-sitemap", {
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
    options: {
      "icon": "src/images/icon.png"
    }
  }, "gatsby-plugin-mdx", "gatsby-transformer-remark", "gatsby-plugin-sharp", "gatsby-transformer-sharp", {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        "name": "images",
        "path": "./src/images/"
      },
      __key: "images"
    }, {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        "name": "pages",
        "path": "./src/pages/"
      },
      __key: "pages"
    }]
};
```

Why doesn't it work with .env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `.env` variables to be accessible on Gatsby's frontend, you [need to prefix those variables with `GATSBY_` prefix](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/#accessing-environment-variables-in-the-browser)

Comment: Hi, I just shared the contents of my configuration file

Comment: Are you sure `NODE_ENV` is set?

Comment: It seems like you also want to [prefix the keys with `GATSBY_`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/#accessing-environment-variables-in-the-browser)

Comment: How do you set NODE_ENV

Comment: @iamaprogrammer Glad to help! :) Please consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in case it resolved your issue